# Does sklearn have group lasso?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm interested in using group lasso for a problem I have.  [Here](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~myuan/papers/glasso.final.pdf) is a link to the algorithm.  I know R has a slick implementation, but am curious to see if python has something similar.

I think `sklearn.linear_model.MultiTaskLasso` might be kind of similar, but am not sure.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It makes me sad when there is something so important which is supported in R, but not in Python. There is no group lasso in sklearn. Please comment on this issue that it is important https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9967

Comment: This function does what's known as multivariate group LASSO, see https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1291388368, using l1/l2 block norm regularization on the coefficient matrix for support union recovery. It's confusing that they refer to it as the multi-task LASSO as that has been used for such models but with an l1/linfinity block norm penalty, see https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/fmri/papers/168-Blockwise-Coord-Descent.pdf; others have also called that "simultaneous LASSO" though, see http://info.deephack.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Hackathon_Theory.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: the skglm package now provides a group lasso in python for scikit-learn, while supporting non convex penalties such as MCP, SCAD or Lq penalties. It also has a very fast group Logistic Regression : https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skglm

Whether or not to implement the Group Lasso in sklearn is discussed in [this issue in the sklearn repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9967), where the conclusion so far is that it is too much of a niche model to justify the maintenance it would need if included in master.

Therefore, I have implemented a `GroupLasso` class which passes sklearn's `check_estimator()` in my python/cython package [celer](https://github.com/mathurinm/celer), which acts as a dropin replacement for sklearn's Lasso, MultitaskLasso, sparse Logistic regression with faster solvers.

The solver uses coordinate descent, working set methods and extrapolation, which should allow it to scale to problems with millions of features.

It supports sparse and dense data, along with centering and normalization (centering sparse data is not trivial as it breaks the sparsity of the design matrix), and comes with a GroupLassoCV class to perform cross-validation.
In [celer's documentation, there is an example](https://mathurinm.github.io/celer/auto_examples/plot_group_lasso.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-group-lasso-py) showing how to use it.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the packages asgl, group-lasso, skglm, celer, please?

Comment: @skan `group-lasso` is no longer maintained, and has problematic active issues IMO (eg, results differ from sklean's lasso when groups are of size 1). `Celer` is very fast but limited to solvers for the Lasso, LogisticRegression and group Lasso
`skglm` has a much broader scope, supports combination of tens of datafits and penalties. It is way more flexible than celer in this aspect, and relies on numba. Both can solve more models, and faster, than scikit-learn

Answer (score 2):

I've also looked into this, as far as I know scikit-learn does not provide this implementation.

The `MultiTaskLasso` does something else. From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#multi-task-lasso): 
"The MultiTaskLasso is a linear model that estimates sparse coefficients for multiple regression problems jointly: `y` is a 2D array, of shape (`n_samples, n_tasks`). The constraint is that the selected features are the same for all the regression problems, also called tasks."

In other words, the `MultiTaskLasso` is an implementation of the Lasso which is able to predict multiple targets at the same time (hence `y` is a 2D array). Another way this problem is known is 'multi-output regression' or '[multi-target regression'](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd). If the tasks are related, such methods can improve methods which try to model every task or target separately.

Answer (score 0):

The Python package [`group-lasso`](https://pypi.org/project/group-lasso/) offers the functionality for group lasso regression (and group lasso logistic regression). It is scikit-learn compliant, that is, objects like [`GroupLasso`](https://group-lasso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#group-lasso-regularised-estimators) and [`LogisticGroupLasso`](https://group-lasso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#group_lasso.LogisticGroupLasso) derive from sklearn's [`BaseEstimator`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html).

Check out the [project's example section](https://group-lasso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/index.html) for some code demonstrations.

If you are familiar with the R-package [`grplasso`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grplasso/index.html), you may want to have a look at [this post](https://github.com/yngvem/group-lasso/issues/38).

Comment: Unfortunately as of 17/08/2023 the source repository https://github.com/yngvem/group-lasso was archived, and is no longer maintained

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a Python package for solving group lasso (and lasso): https://github.com/JamesYang007/adelie. It is largely inspired by the popular R package `glmnet` (I am one of the authors). Unfortunately, `glmnet` does not support group lasso and it requires some extra tricks to implement an efficient version. Aside from this, there are some other shortcomings of `glmnet` (e.g. only works for dense or sparse matrices), which are fixed with this new package.